# Button Click not working in update panel only in IE9

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, internet-explorer-9

Currenly i am working on asp.net c# project.

I use select2 in update panel.

My button Click is not working after Postback.

I use this Code to rebind this JQuery Plugin in update panel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var frm = document.getElementById("aspnetForm");
        if (frm) {
            frm.onsubmit = function () { return false; };
        }

  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
                bind();
            }
        }
   function bind() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".chzn-select").select2();
            $(".option-listing").select2();
        });
    }
    </script>
```

After postback button click is not working only in IE9. No Console Error.. 
In other browser work properly.

If i Comment this `Bind()` function my button is work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check here if your jquery framework is compatible with ie9
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx